# Mongoose have same function for save and update middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a question: how does one make middleware run on two different hooks?
I want to replace this code:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (!this.localAuth.password) next();
  this.localAuth.password = this.generateHash(this.localAuth.password);
  next();
})
userSchema.pre('update', function(next) {
  if (!this.localAuth.password) next();
  this.localAuth.password = this.generateHash(this.localAuth.password);
  next();
})
```

With something like this:

```
userSchema.pre('saveOrUpdate', function(next) {
  if (!this.localAuth.password) next();
  this.localAuth.password = this.generateHash(this.localAuth.password);
  next();
})
```

Notice how the functions are the same, I just need a hook that is runs on save and update. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: available middleware : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate function for authentication and then call it from both hooks.

```
function auth ( next ) {
    //do stuff here
    if (!this.localAuth.password) next();
    this.localAuth.password = this.generateHash(this.localAuth.password);
    next();
}

//for save operation
userSchema.pre("save", auth);

//update operation 
userSchema.pre("update", auth);
```